# run FreeBSD 10 (as guest) under Xen on Linux

Tags: linux, freebsd, xen

I have my Linux/Debian/Sid amd64 (with i7 3770K, 16Gb RAM, 1 SSD + 2 hard disks) PC with xen (notably I have installed a package `xen-linux-system-amd64`), so

```
 sudo xen list
 Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs State   Time(s)
 Domain-0                                     0 16016     8     r-----    2634.8
```

<sup>I am understanding that the Dom0 is my Linux 4.0 kernel & system; I have `xen-hypervisor-4.5-amd`...</sup>

I have a disk with two partitions for FreeBSD

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 465.8 GiB, 500106780160 bytes, 976771055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x624aeae3

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1            2048 754976767 754974720  360G 83 Linux
/dev/sdd2       754976768 773851135  18874368    9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdd3       773851136 792725503  18874368    9G b8 BSDI swap
/dev/sdd4       792725504 976771054 184045551 87.8G b7 BSDI fs
```

(BTW, this is not my system disk; `/dev/sdd1` is for my `/xtra` Linux ext4 file system, and `dev/sdd2` is my second swap partition)

I would like to run FreeBSD, probably only on the command line since I don't need to run X11 server under FreeBSD, (preferably FreeBSD 10.1 for x86-64 architecture) *under xen* using `/dev/sdd4` for its root (and only) filesystem and `/dev/sdd3` for its swap area. But I am not sure of how to proceed next.

Should I download [*FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso*](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/ISO-IMAGES/10.1/FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso) or what? What are the next steps to run it under xen? The http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/How_to_Install_a_FreeBSD_domU_on_a_Linux_Host page is not helpful enough (& https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/virtualization-guest.html don't mention xen)

FWIW, I am an old Unixer (my first Unix was SunOS3.2 on Sun3/160 in the mid 1980s) and my main motivation for trying FreeBSD is to check that my [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) software (a GPLv3 plugin for recent GCC to easily extend and customize GCC in a Lisp-like language) can be used on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find an accurate guide for setting up FreeBSD 10 as a domU under Xen either, [I wrote my own](http://blog.packetdisarray.com/2015/08/11/freebsd-10-pvhvm-xen/). I believe you're using a newer OS release and Xen version than me, but the process should be similar. Here's the gist:

1. Download a FreeBSD 10 ISO (I used FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso) and put `console="comconsole"` in its `/boot/loader.conf` to let you install over a serial console. If you know how to use VNC instead, that should be fine too -- in that case, ignore what I say about using serial. The FreeBSD handbook has [detailed instructions on extracting and recreating the ISO](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/install-advanced.html).
2. Allocate disk partitions and MAC addresses, and create your domU configuration. Here's mine:

   ```
   memory = 1024
   name = "eagle"

   # PVHVM stuff
   builder = "hvm"
   kernel = "hvmloader"
   boot = "dc"

   vif = [ 'mac=00:16:3E:01:AB:23' ]
   disk = [ 'phy:/dev/solid-state/eagle-disk,hda,w',
            'file:/virt/iso/FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-amd64-headless.iso,hdb:cdrom,r'
          ]

   # Necessary for getting the serial console in `xm console`
   serial = "pty"
   ```
3. Start the domU and install as normal. At the `mountroot` prompt after the bootloader but before the installer, use `?` to enumerate your options -- you probably want something like `cd9660:cd0`.

   At the end of the installation process, choose to open a shell in the newly-installed system and put `console="comconsole"` in its `/boot/loader.conf` as well. Then, shut down the domU.
4. In your domU configuration file, change `boot = "dc"` to `boot = "c"` to boot from the disk you installed to rather than the ISO. You can also remove the ISO's `disk` entry if you want.
5. Start the domU -- at this point, you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

As one approach that I'd estimate could work, though I've yet to get up and running with Xen myself: The FreeBSD foundation publishes a pre-installed VMDK edition of the FreeBSD base system [[where](https://www.freebsd.org/where.html)][[amd64](http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/VM-IMAGES/10.1-RELEASE/amd64/Latest/)][[i386](http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/VM-IMAGES/10.1-RELEASE/i386/Latest/)]. The Xen project, moreover, provides some documentation about installing a VMDK under Xen, using QEMU tools [[Migration from VMware](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Migration_from_VMware)].  Naturally, this assumes that there is an operating system environment where the QEMU tools would be available.

Assuming that it may be a relatively straightforward process, then towards installing ports and packages and configuring the the virtual machine after its first boot, I'd recommend [The FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/index.html) as a reference.

Personally, I'm not greatly familiar with the Xen architecture. I'm not sure how an *Install from ISO* might proceed with the same. The VMDK image can also be  used with [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org), for applications on non-Xen-dom0 architectures -- personally, I've found some successes with the same, towards a simple XFCE desktop albeit in a *virtual guest* image on a proprietary operating system. I've read some advice about how Xen can be installed bare-metal on a Microsoft Windows PC, but with UEFI on my laptop, it's nothing I've ventured about as yet.